# Process Builder Rule not running on Salesforce CPQ Quote Lines?

Tags: formula, process-builder, cpq

I have a process builder flow I need to run whenever a product is added to a quote and recorded as a quote line. To my understanding this created a new quote line.

Right now the formula that it uses to determine if it fires is:

```
OR(!ISCHANGED([SBQQ__QuoteLine__c].Subscription_Increment_Type__c ), ISNEW())
```

Shouldn't this be triggered whenever a new record is entered, or the record is updated and the Subscription_Increment_Type field isn't changed?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve? Perhaps u can share a screenshot where u are facing an issue so that I can understand ur requirement

Comment: @DhananjayPatil I'm trying to automatically set a value on a custom field that is copied over from the Product when the Quote Line is added, but that can be changed afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your formula. You can't use isChanged in formula section anymore as it's deprecated in spring'15.

**The above formula can be achieved by below two steps**

While selecting object in process builder, select the option **when a record is created or edited**
[image]

In criteria action group section, you need to use **IsChanged** operator instead of using it in formula

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per ur last comment you are copying custom field value of product to Custom field of Quote Line Item(correct me if I am wrong).

In order to achieve this,u may have created process builder for Quote Line Item.
The formula that you have mentioned in description,it looks like you want to copy the value only when you create quote line item.

In the process builder **condition** you can create your formula like this:

```
If(AND(ISBLANK([QuoteLineItem].Description ),ISNEW()),true,false)
```

In the above formula,I am copying the value of product description to Line Item description.I am checking if the Line item description field is blank and record is newly created.if formula sets to true then it copies the value of product description to line item description.

Below is the formula for **immediate action**.

- Action Name--->Name of Action
- Criteria for Updating Records-->No Criteria

[QuoteLineItem].Product2.Description

**After record is created and if I want to change the line item description then process builder will not trigger and I can update the description accordingly.**

This is just an example that I have shown to you.you have to replace the fields with the custom field of yours in formula.

Let me know if it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a Price Rule instead of a Process Builder on Quote Lines.  Price Actions support the use of formulas.